# PHP - time minus time to minutes

Tags: php

In php i have two times - 11:00:00 and 12:45:00. I want to get the difference between them in minutes, in this case 105 minutes. Whats the best way that can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: PHP strtotime(), mysql TIMEDIFF()

Comment: DateTime (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php); its diff() method (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php); and DateInterval (http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) with its format() method (http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 60
```

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a very useful function. It returns the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for a wide variety of times and dates. So, if you take the two timestamps, and subtract them, then you have the difference in seconds. Divide by 60 to get the minutes.

Comment: @user1985273 Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $time_diff = strtotime('2013-03-13 12:45:00') - strtotime('2013-03-13 11:00:00');
    echo $time_diff/60;
```

I just kept dates as not sure if I keep the time part only it would return the correct diff or not.

EDIT

I just tested it works without date too ...

```
    $time_diff = strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00');
    echo $time_diff/60;
```

So to answer you question - strtotime() returns a timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC) so you simply divide it by 60 to convert it result into minutes.

Comment: Got the same anwser from Duotrigesimal, but still, thank you too! :)