# Time minus time to time on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, time

I have a string time  `$a = "17:20:00";`
I want to do

```
  if($a > "13:00:00"){
    $c = $a - "01:00:00";
  }
```

I want to get `$c = "16:20:00"`
How can this be done?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, try to Google a little, and you find this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: did you do any research? check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391942/php-time-minus-time-to-minutes
use 'strtotime` function for subtraction.

Comment: You need to convert the string  by using `strtotime()` and then subtract the time from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a is a string and can't be compared like that.
Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to make it UNIX time (integer) and subtract 3600 seconds.
And then use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert back to string.

```
$a = strtotime("17:20:00");
    if($a > strtotime("13:00:00")){
        $c = $a - 3600;
}

Echo date("H:i", $c);
```

https://3v4l.org/fOggP

Comment: Thank you! I have solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
if(strtotime($a) > strtotime("13:00:00")){
    $c = date( "h:i:s", strtotime($a) - strtotime("01:00:00")); 
  }
```

You should try this!!!

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-strtotime-convert-to-time-format/6180/2)